# How to send an attachment mail using wp_mail mail

Tags: wordpress, email

Is there anyone to tell me that how to send an attachment email using `wp_mail` function of wordpress?
I am using the following code but its not working

```
$attachments = array(ABSPATH . '/uploads/abc.png');
wp_mail($email, 'Testing Attachment' , 'This is subscription',$attachments);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this and let me know then --

```
$attachments = array(ABSPATH . '/uploads/abc.png');
wp_mail($email, 'Testing Attachment' , 'This is subscription','This is for header',$attachments);
```

Your attachment is setting as header in this case.

Comment: Thnx a lot man @swapnesh its working now, m feel really happy :)

Comment: This does not work. I used `WP_CONTENT_DIR`.


`$mail_attachment = array(WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/uploads/image.png');`

Comment: and where is the image in email?